# How to animate element repositioning when ng-repeat filter is applied

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-animate

I have a bootstrap grid layout (2 columns) of divs (basically vcard profiles).

It works with an ng-repeat, creating `<div class="col-sm-6"></div>` for each vcard.

It has a filter box at the top that filters the cards, and it works great.

I would like if when the filters are applied, instead of cards disappearing, reappearing, and moving to their new location instantaneously, I would like them to shuffle into and out of place so we can see the cards move from their current location to their new location to fill the gap left by a card that disappeared.

I have basic animations already working - the cards just fade out. But I'm not sure out to make them shuffle into and out of place. What kind of animation do I need?

**EDIT**

This is kind of what I want, except to work with ngrepeat filter, not just resize of screen.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Ffgrxq?p=preview

Comment: 4,000 rep and you aren't showing us code or a demo? Dude!

Comment: haha. well I think this is probably just easy and common and I just don't know where to get started.

Comment: what you are asking for is quite a complex implementation that would require writing a custom cs3 animation sequence.

Comment: @Claies Is that right?

Comment: Just added an edit with an example.

Comment: When Angular updates the DOM it rewrites it. It doesn't move things around with positioning. For this reason it's not as simple as using CSS transitions.

Comment: @isherwood...damn, I was afraid of that.

Comment: I guess a better description is that I want the flow to be animated.

Comment: take a look if this can help you http://www.nganimate.org/angularjs/ng-repeat/move

Comment: thanks...this is exactly what I want: http://jsfiddle.net/g/3SH7a/

Comment: http://passy.github.io/angular-masonry/

Comment: Thanks @isherwood I will try that too!

Comment: how did it go @richard :D